Matlab logic of plotting meshgrid formula
There is a code which uses meshgrid which is basicly doing all combination of one vector with the size of the other vector and visa versa.
y and z are values of the field in the Y axes and Z axes.
In the sum_a_m expression there are .* * / and ./ expresson with the meshgrid Y and Z.
What is the logic in that?
Thanks.
  y=linspace(-y_lim,y_lim,600);
    z=linspace(-z_lim,z_lim,600);
    [Y,Z]=meshgrid(y,z);
    sum_a_m=0;
    for m=-300:300
       %sum of evanacent wave coefficients
       if(m~=0)
       a_m=-1i*sqrt(k^2-k_t_m^2);
       sum_a_m=sum_a_m+(exp(-1i*(2*pi*m/d)*Y).*exp(-a_m*abs(Z))./a_m);
       end
    end
   
    E_total_2_51=E_0*exp(-1i*k*Y*sin(theta_in)).*exp(-1i*k*Z*cos(theta_in)) ...
    -((eta*I0)/(2*cos(theta_in)*d)).*exp(-1i*k*Y*sin(theta_in)).*exp(-1i*k*abs(Z)*cos(theta_in))...
    -(((1i*k*eta*I0)/(2*d)).*exp(-1i*k.*Y*sin(theta_in)).*sum_a_m);


Is your question about difference between * and .* operators (which has nothing to do with meshgrid()?

Its about what is the logic of doing such meshgrid

Please clarify what you mean by "what is the logic of". It is not clear what you are asking, do you mean what is the purpose of doing a Meshgrid? What is it you want to do and what isn't clear about the description Matlab provides: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html (Please update your answer to be clearer on what the question actually is). Thanks

May this helps: meshgrid() is just a convenience function to simplify  working with functions of two variables.
Let's assume you want to calculate $x = e^{-\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}$ on a 2D grid. Typically this will require a double loop, i.e.
 for iy = 1:length(y)
   for iz = 1:length(z)
     x(iy,iz) = exp(-sqrt(y(iy).^2 + z(iz).^2));
   end
 end

meshgrid() expands the two 1D grids into a single 2D grid and you can simply write
 [Y,Z]=meshgrid(y,z);
 x = exp(-sqrt(Y.^2+Z.^2));

So it's just easier to read and write.

meshgrid generates 2D variables that in turn are used to solve without for loops and most of times faster than using for loops.
Operators * and / are conventional product and division
[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]*[1 0 -1;3 7 -1;5 8 -9]
 =
  22    38   -30
  49    83   -63
  76   128   -96

.* and ./ are element-by-element operations aka dot-product and dot-division.
[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9].*[1 0 -1;3 7 -1;5 8 -9]
=
     1     0    -3
    12    35    -6
    35    64   -81

The logic is to write faster and more compact programs.
meshgrid builds 2D variables that in turn do not require (most of times, like 99%) for loops and MATHWORKS optimized such functions to work (again most of times, ~99%) faster than using nested for loops.
